# Auto move table to hidden table

Tags: livecycle-designer

I have two tables in my PDF (situated just above and bottom of each other). Only one table will be shown depending on another checkbox.

Currently I'm facing issue when the first table has its presence set to invisible, there will be a huge blank space then only the second table shown. I want to achieve the effect where the second table will replace the blank space of first table where first table being hidden.

I have tried setting the Content attribute of the tables and subform wrapping the tables to "Flowed" but it doesn't work.

Comment: hi to the person who down voted me, please leave the reason so that I can improvise & learn from my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question by a "move around" way.

I merged the two tables' rows into one tables then hide show the rows instead which makes it looks like only one table is shown at one time while will not having blank space if the first table is hidden.

Though I still believe that there should be method to have two actual tables at the same time while not having blank space if first table is hidden. I will remain this question open for another week in case a *real* answer is posted else I will accept this answer.